# Returning child nodes where there is a HABTM association in Rails API using Rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I am using the popular [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) gem for producing a JSON API in Rails. However, I am having some difficulty understanding how to return results of a HABTM association. I have a model called Sale and a model called Merchandise. A HABTM association is specified for each. My .rabl file looks like the following.

object @sales

```
attributes :name, :date_start, :date_end

child :merchandises do
    attributes :name
end
```

My model is simply passing @sales = Sale.all.

Nothing at all is returned in the child, even though many rows have valid relationships. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking out https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/149 issue. Perhaps do:

```
collection @sales
attributes :name, :date_start, :date_end
node :merchandises do |s|
  s.merchandises.to_a.map { |m| { :name => m.name } }
end
```

and see if that works any better?